# Azure UploadFromFileAsync returns bad request

Tags: .net, azure, model-view-controller, cloud, storage

I am trying to simply upload a file using the CloudFileClient but running into what seems like an odd response.  I took the sample code directly from the Azure sample File Store project that comes with the SDK.

My code does exactly the same steps:

```
string connection = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureFileStorage");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection);

// Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

// Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("documents");
await share.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

// Get a reference to the root directory of the share.        
CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

// Put files in this user's folder
CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference(User.Identity.GetUserId());
await dir.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

// Save the document to Azure File Storage
if (System.IO.File.Exists(model.DocumentPath))
{
    CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference(model.DocumentPath);
    await file.UploadFromFileAsync(model.DocumentPath, FileMode.Open);
}
```

The last line returns a 400 bad request.  I check in my Azure portal that the sub-directory was successfully made, and I can manually upload files through the azure portal, but when I try the sample code and I know the file path is good, the async call always gives me a yellow page with a 400.

I am not using datetimes, my container name doesn't start with a capital letter, the file I am trying to upload is only a few K

The Storage Uri in the CloudFile is
    StorageUri  {Primary = 'https://mydomain.file.core.windows.net/documents//C:%5Cdev%5Creadme.txt'; Secondary = ''}

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the following line of code:

```
CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference(model.DocumentPath);
```

Just to test things out, please change the following to something like:

```
CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference("readme.txt");
```

Basically what is happening is that you're setting the entire file path (`C:\dev\readme.txt`) as the name of the Azure File instead of just `readme.txt` and there is a `:` character in the name of the Azure File which is not getting escaped properly.

Comment: My code was originally like that, but I got an error looking for the file in my IIS directory as it was the default path.  Is there a way I can select a file from anywhere in the file system since I'd like a user to be able to select a file from their computer to upload.